# Namespace android.support.design is not bound

Tags: android, android-layout

Code snippet where this issue crops up :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/lastName_layout"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android.support.design:hintTextAppearance="@color/colorAccent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lastName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#E0E0E0"
        android:hint="Last Name"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Error appears in the last line of the first block. How is the namespace supposed to be defined?

Answer (score 4):

You need add the dependency for this works:

```
xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
   android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   design:menu="@menu/main_menu_nav" />
```

design:menu -> now works fine.

Comment: This is the right solution. I had a similar issue where I wanted to use `android.support.v7.appcompat:titleTextColor` on the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` widget. The solution was to add the line `xmlns:android.support.v7.appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to the root element of the layout.

Answer (score 1):

To allow access to the namespace in the whole layout file add the following as an attribute to the root element:

```
xmlns:android.support.design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

You can also shorten the namespace if you would like.

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

And then

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/lastName_layout"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@color/colorAccent">
```